# Spring Boot and OpenJPA: Injecting EntityManager via @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, openjpa

So I am trying to inject an entity manager obviously in my Spring Boot app, however it keeps failing to start up because it cannot find a bean with name "myPersistenceUnitName" although it has been clearly defined as such in my persistence.xml.

I have of course fished around a little bit, but haven't gotten a clear answer besides maybe adding some thing called `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to a Spring app context XML file. I really do not want to use this approach because I would strongly prefer to minimize the amount of non-Java code I have.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you're using Boot you wouldn't use a `persistence.xml`. Is there a particular reason why you are?

Comment: Just the code I was given, so I'm not entirely sure. Do I not need to specify the name of the persistence unit then? Because that's not behaving how I expect

Comment: Most of the time, if there's only a single persistence unit you don't need to name it. That's usually only necessary if you have multiple (unusual) and need to distinguish them.

Comment: Looks like the XML is mandated by our build script in order for OpenJPA to enhance the entity classes at build time. There are two persistence units in this XML too, but referring to either by name or commenting one out and referring to the other by name still don't work.